# Linux - Is there a way to call to system call (bash scripts) without forking a new process?

Tags: c++, linux

In my c++ apps, I need to run several bash scripts. (sometimes regular system calls, i.e "shutdown" , "rm").
When using the "system" call, it forks a new process.

Is there a way to call "system" without forking a new process ?

Comment: `exec()` directly replaces your process with the new one being invoked. As such, it doesn't (need to) fork.

Comment: ...that said, those are your choices -- either you start a new process (with fork, clone, or similar) or you have your own process replace itself with the thing you're running, in which case it no longer exists.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy or write the code to not rely on warts like `system()` by using C (or C++, as appropriate) library calls...

Comment: @twalberg, indeed. I was hoping that the OP used the phrase "system call" with a mistaken thinking that it was a generic term, rather than in reference to the start-a-shell-running-this-command libc function.

Answer (score 1):

Not easily. But if you're willing to add complexity to your setup, you could:

1. make your program itself do the system calls that `rm`, `shutdown`, etc would do (you'd be reinventing the wheel, though)
2. write a script that listens to commands given on a port and executes the commands (and keep the script running -- perhaps as a daemon). Complex and fragile...

Then you wouldn't need to `fork()` or call `exec`...  But it's better to just fork a new process, or use `exec` -- I see no advantage in doing things different in this situation.

Comment: Eh? For a shutdown, one can simply execve(), since you don't expect to continue running regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually, there are analogs of these bash commands in standard libc library.
But nevetherless if you want to try ... I wanna to say how about exploits?
I mean, in this case there will be no syscalls (exclude exploits's).

Comment: Huh? "No syscalls" is a very, very different thing from "no system() calls"... and, well, rather a lot of exploits tend to require syscalls. Also, by definition, they're exceedingly fragile -- no way to run production code.

Answer (score 0):

No, because running a script means running an instance of bash and/or other executable binary.

Although for most of regular system calls there is corresponding C function, which of course doesn't fork the process (like for example [unlink()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/unlink.html) for `rm`).

EDIT: I know about `exec*` functions, but if OP wants to run *several* commands they are useless, maybe except for running the last one.

Comment: -1, flatly incorrect (doesn't acknowledge existance of execve(), which is certainly a plausible option for invoking a shutdown, since your process doesn't expect to live through same).